# How do I indicate a cut for a dotted line in a dieline?

Tags: print-production, dieline, diecut

I made a packaging design for a rectangular box and I'm trying to figure out how to indicate when a line is not simply FOLDED (as indicated with a dotted line) but **CUT as a dotted line**.

Comment: When you say "CUT as a dotted line", are you referring to a perforation, where something can be detached?

Answer (score 1):

Standard procedure in the packaging industry is to have a separate spot colour (and sometimes a separate layer too) for creases and cuts. So if you follow this rule, create a **creases** spot colour and a **cuts** spot colour and then a crease would be dashed line coloured as **crease** and the perforation would be dashed line coloured as **cut**. If necessary, you could have a third colour and separate layer for dimensions and notes.

However, this may all be besides the point because the usual process would be for the printer or finisher to provide a cutter guide and maybe even some samples based on your design brief. You should only be doing it if it's just for a mockup or an academic exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're asking how to show that the item should be *cut* along a certain line?

I'd say the most common (and simplest) way of doing this is by placing scissors on the cut line, kind of like I did below:

[image]